# Rotas Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.6

Senhores estou tendo problemas na hora de setar as rodas e me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
{
    throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
}
```

Estou fazendo elas da seguinte maneira:

route/web.php

```
$this->post('cadastrar-sub-categoria', 'CategoriaController@cadastrarSubCategoria')->name('cadastrarSubCategoria');
```

controller.php

```
public function cadastrarSubCategoria(){
    return 'OK';
}
```

Onde posso estar errando? Estou iniciando os estudos em laravel 5.6!

Obrigado.

Comment: Se você está acessando isso via navegador, é `GET`. Você criou uma rota `POST`

Comment: Valew @DiegoSouza, era isso! Obrigado